# Presenting logistic regression tables for non-binary categorical variables (Stata)

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, stata, reporting

For my logistic regression model I have a couple of non-binary categorical predictors (e.g income level and education) with more than three categories. My question now is how to present findings for these variables elegantly; is there any other way than to include the coefficients for each category when using the `estout` command for example? Otherwise the table would be extremely large. What is the standard procedure here?